# Make lightcase.js full screen at all times?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm using this lightbox plugin: http://cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/#demo

In the demos, when you shrink the browser width you will see the vertical scrollbar disappear.  Can anybody tell me how to accomplish this behaviour for all browser widths?  I've tried to trace the CSS but I just can't find it.  I thought it would be overflow:hidden but I think there's more to it than that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have similar results, have you find an answer?

Comment: I didn't unfortunately.  Sorry.